# Android background services constantly restarting

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I just got an LG Risio (Leon/Tribute2/etc) running Lollipop 5.1.1 and I'm having a problem with several of my apps not working properly because their background services are constantly being restarted. If I reboot the phone, the services are running fine and the apps work, but after a while (not any particular amount of time), the services show as "Restarting" in the "Running" Apps screen and the functions they're supposed to perform stop working.

The issue looks exactly like the one listed here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93545/apps-are-automatically-closing-restarting-and-phone-is-running-slow

The thing is, that's 5.0, and that was a memory leak that was supposedly fixed already, so I'm not sure what would be causing this.

WATYF

Answer (score 0):

I think, this can help you: 
[Service.startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification))

Comment: These aren't apps that I've written.

Answer (score 0):

It possibly is an Android Lollipop 5.1.1 bug, which hasn't been fixed through the updates yet.
If not, maybe reinstalling Lollipop could fix the issue

Comment: How would I reinstall Lollipop? Are you talking about a factory reset?

Comment: No, not a factory reset. This link could help you:
http://www.gottabemobile.com/2015/05/01/how-to-install-android-5-1-1-lollipop-right-now/